# Mathematica residual miscalculation

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to apply the residual theorem of Complex analysis for the calculation of an inverse Laplace operator. My function is the following:

`f1[s_]:=-(0.000879451/((0.00024674 + s) (-s + 100. (1 - 1/z)))) + 0.00879451/((0.0024674 + s) (-s + 100. (1 - 1/z)))`

I calculate the poles of the function as:

`poles = s /. Solve[Denominator[Together[Expand[f1[s]]]] == 0] // Chop`

Then I use the Residue function of *Mathematica* at the poles:

`Residue[f1[s], {s, #}] & /@ poles // Simplify`

To get:

`{0, (8.79449*10^-6 z)/(0.999998 - 1. z), -((0.0000791484 (-1. + z) z)/(0.999973 - 1.99997 z + 1. z^2))}`

However, the first term is clearly wrong. I did the calculation manually to find:

`Simplify[(s - poles[[1]])*Expand[f1[s]],Assumptions -> s != poles[[1]]] /. s -> poles[[1]] // Simplify`

which gives,

`-((0.0000879429 z)/(0.999975 - 1. z))`

Can someone point out what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Can't reproduce with `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I use mathematica 12.2.0.0 Platform Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: I cannot reproduce with "12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)".

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The results obtained from V13.3 are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Solve` produces the warning message,

> > Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The
> > answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and
> > numericizing the result.

you might try rationalizing `f1[s]` (here `f` for simplicity):

```
f = Simplify@Rationalize[-(0.000879451/((0.00024674 + s) (-s + 
       100. (1 - 1/z)))) + 0.00879451/((0.0024674 + s) (-s + 100. (1 - 1/z))), 0]
(* -((1978764750000 s z)/((12337 + 5000000 s) (12337 + 50000000 s) (100 + (-100 + s) z))) *)

poles = s /. Solve[Denominator[f] == 0]
(* {-(12337/5000000), -(12337/50000000), (100 (-1 + z))/z} *)

Residue[f, {s, #}] & /@ poles // Simplify
(* {(879451 z)/(20 (-500000000 + 500012337 z)), 
   -((879451 z)/(20 (-5000000000 + 5000012337 z))), 
   -((197876475000000 (-1 + z) z)/((-500000000 + 500012337 z) (-5000000000 + 5000012337 z)))} *)
```

which eliminates precision issues.